# How to extract length/width from c++ face bounding box

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV c++ to compute the bounding box of a face. I am using this code:

```
haarClassifier.detectMultiScale(frameGray, boxes, 1.1, 6, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, minFaceSize);
```

When I cout `boxes` to the terminal, I get this kind of result:

```
[485 x 485 from (358, 138)]
```

This is all the information I need, but I'm not sure how to extract out length/width and the starting coordinate without converting to string and indexing, which is definitely not the best way.

Essentially, I want to do this because I am trying to break the box up into 4 quadrants. In this example, I want to do the following (pseudocode):

```
// get box dimensions/coords
length = 485
width = 485
top_left_x_coord = 358
top_left_y_coord = 138

// create quadrants
quadrant_length = length/2
quadrant_width = length/2

top_left_x_coord = 358
top_left_y_coord = 138

top_right_x_coord = top_left_x_coord + quadrant_width
top_right_y_coord = top_left_y_coord

bottom_left_x_coord = top_left_x_coord
bottom_left_y_coord = top_left_y_coord + quadrant_length

bottom_right_x_coord = bottom_left_x_coord + quadrant_width
bottom_right_y_coord = bottom_left_y_coord

// return the following

// top-left
[length x width from (top_left_x_coord, top_left_y_coord)]
// top-right
[length x width from (top_right_x_coord, top_right_y_coord)]
// bottom-left
[length x width from (bottom_left_x_coord, bottom_left_y_coord)]
// bottom-right
[length x width from (bottom_right_x_coord, bottom_right_y_coord)]
```

What is the best, most c++ way, to extract out the length, width, x and y from `[485 x 485 from (358, 138)]` so I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**do not** convert it to string and attempt to parse it.

please [look up that method](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#pub-attribs) on docs.opencv.org

you are given a vector of `cv::Rect`

use docs.opencv.org to find out how to access parts of a [`cv::Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#pub-attribs). the Rect type has numeric fields.